# Tail a massive log file in Windows

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, logging, tail

Inherited an IIS server when I started a new job. The previous "admin" had no log management policy in place. I'm now staring at a 56GB .log file that was created by a piece of software running in the background. I'm looking for a way to cut the log down to the last 50MB dump and keep it that way. Any suggestions?

There are also 63GB of IIS logs, but those I can deal with.

Comment: Do you need the contents of the log? Why not move/archive it somewhere and let the application start a new log file?

Comment: I don't want to have to worry about this anymore. If i start a new file, yes, it's going to be smaller, at first. Eventually it'll grow to what I have now. I'm looking for a more permanent solution without rewriting the logging part of the application.

Comment: So use a scheduled task to move and rename the log file every x amount of time and let the program create a new one as @joeqwerty suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @jeiqwerty @JBaldrige.

Wrote a batch file that is now set up to run once a day:

```
move "%ROOT_FOLDER%\nettrace.log" "%ROOT_FOLDER%\history\nettrace.log"
ren "%%ROOT_FOLDER%\history\nettrace.log" "%ROOT_FOLDER%\history\nettrace-%date:/=-%.log"
forfiles -p "%ROOT_FOLDER%\history" -s -m *.* -d -2 -c "cmd /c del @file"
```